# Invalid editor window of type: UnityEditor.CurveEditorWindow

Tags: unity-game-engine

when after I run the game to test gameplay,
I had to maximize the game window but it canceled and the console displays this error.
I use AnimationCurve in my enemy pattern.
I have been editing AnimationCurve and at the finish of edit, I close the AnimationCurve editor window.
I can`t find problem.
The unity version is 2021.3.11f1.

```cs
Invalid editor window of type: UnityEditor.CurveEditorWindow, title: Curve
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallDelayFunctions ()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5brB.png)

First
I closed the editor Curve Window before gameplay.
but failed.
Second
I close Unity, opened it, and did not open the AnimationCurve editor before playing the game..
Succes.
but do I need to close Unity after I edit the animation curve?

Comment: `but do I need to close Unity after I edit the animation curve?` .. shouldn't ^^ just to confirm you can reproduce this by editing an animation curve, close the window, then entering playmode?

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I've had a lot of these problems, too.

When you encounter these problems for the first time, you are often embarrassed.

These problems are often simple Unity bugs.
Click windows - layouts - levert factory settings to resolve this issue.
Then it will be solved normally.

Have a nice day.

Comment: It worked beautifully. why someone wants to downgrade the correct answers

Comment: Oddly enough, this seems to have stopped the error for me. Must be a Unity bug.